# get null pointer error when loading the sounds into soundpool

Tags: java, android, soundpool

what am I doing wrong?
any help would be greatly apreciated
the log shows the initAudio method called and sound pool created then crashes

```
 public class soundEffects extends Activity{
    SoundPool sp;
    int shot = 0;
    public void InitializeAudio(){
    Log.d("TEST", "initAudio method called");
       sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
       Log.d("TEST", "sound pool created sp= " + sp);
       shot = sp.load(this, R.raw.gunshot, 1);
       Log.d("TEST", "Audio is loaded :)");
    }

    public void fireSound(){
        Log.d("TEST", "fire sound method works");
        sp.play(shot, 1, 1, 0,0, 1);
        Log.d("TEST", "fire sound command sucessful");

    }


    }
```

Stack Trace(I think this is it)  -----------------------------------------------------------

```
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617): Process: com.example.firedatgun_v2, PID: 14617
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firedatgun_v2/com.example.firedatgun_v2.Display}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2232)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1225)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5186)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.media.SoundPool$SoundPoolImpl.load(SoundPool.java:491)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:159)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.example.firedatgun_v2.soundEffects.InitializeAudio(soundEffects.java:15)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.example.firedatgun_v2.gun.reload(gun.java:32)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.example.firedatgun_v2.Display.onCreate(Display.java:26)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1098)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2196)
12-24 11:31:43.074: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: Where do you get the exception?  Which line?  Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: It seems like `sp` is null. However, looking at your code that should be impossible. Try to print its value to the log. Next time, please add the stacktrace as well.

Comment: Also, please start following Java naming conventions - `PascalCase` for classes; `camelCase` for methods. It'll make it a lot easier for anyone else to read your code.

Comment: 12-24 11:24:51.935: D/TEST(14027): sound pool created sp= android.media.SoundPool@64b2b530

Comment: That's not the stack trace.  That's the logger statement you have.  Can you post the stack trace:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: It seems to be failing here:  `sp.load(this, R.raw.gunshot, 1);`  Does `R.raw` and `R.raw.gunshot` exist?  What about the `Context` (`this`)?

Comment: It has been solved, look at the answer below, I know that was the problematic like e of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing an invalid Activity, in this case the `soundEffect` class. Just extending the Activity class won't give you all the pleasures of an Activity unless that Activity is explicitly called with onCreate(...) to set-up resources, etc.

You can remove the "extends Activity" from you `soundEffects` class, and instead, replace your

```
public void InitializeAudio()
{
   Log.d("TEST", "initAudio method called");
   sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
   Log.d("TEST", "sound pool created sp= " + sp);
   shot = sp.load(this, R.raw.gunshot, 1);
   Log.d("TEST", "Audio is loaded :)");
}
```

with

```
public void InitializeAudio(Context context)
{
   Log.d("TEST", "initAudio method called");
   sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
   Log.d("TEST", "sound pool created sp= " + sp);
   shot = sp.load(context, R.raw.gunshot, 1);
   Log.d("TEST", "Audio is loaded :)");
}
```

And pass a reference from you main Activity, which would appear to be your `Display` class, up through `gun.reload(..)`, which should be `gun.reload(Context context)`.

Comment: i did that and passed getBaseContext() to the method InitializeAudio, thank you, I really appreciate your help